# Why is Google Drive not displaying the contents of my sub-folder?

Tags: file-upload, google-drive-api, google-colaboratory

I have a dataset folder "*f1*" containing 2 class folders "*f1_1*" and "*f1_2*" on my local system. In each of these, there are about 10000, 256x256 pixel image tiles. Total space taken up by "*f1*" is ~2-3 GB.

To upload the files to Google Drive, I first zip "*f1*", read the compressed file and un-compress it in Colab.

After this is done, I check the folders on Google Drive, where one of the sub-folders (either "*f1_1*" or "*f1_2*") is empty and has no files while the other one does. I know this can happen when the Drive memory is running out - at the time of reporting this, I had > 50 GB memory free on the Drive

Any ideas as to what exactly is happening here ?

Code for extracting contents of "zip" file:

```
from zipfile import ZipFile

with ZipFile(zip_file_path, 'r') as zip:
  zip.extractall(path='path_location_where_contents_need_to_be_extracted')
```

Comment: How are you uploading the files to Google Drive? Using Google APIs or manually adding the file to colab? or Directly to Google Drive?

Comment: @GiselleValladares I compress my data folder on my local system and upload the ".zip" file directly to Google Drive.